# Need messages in Gmail Trash to last longer

Tags: gmail, online-storage

Is there a way to make Gmail store messages up to three (3) years in "Trash" before they really remove it?

Currently, emails sitting in Trash are automatically deleted after 30 days. I would like this to be longer. I'm okay if they do that at the expense of my storage space.

Comment: Now, why would someone want to look in a 3 years old trash? You're definitely mistaking it by **archive**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Archive your messages instead of deleting them/moving them to the trash.

Alternatively, you could create a "Trash" or "Deleted" label, then change the label settings to not "show in message list". Move your "deleted" messages to that label/folder and purge every few years!

Comment: @Pacerier `archive` just means `remove inbox label`. The "*second option*" is **adding** a label - and arguably you'd want to archive it as well.