# Archive all my current messages in Trash in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

I want to archive all my current messages in Trash in Gmail, but can't find the archive button anywhere.

How do I archive trashed messages?

Comment: now, that question just became **much better** than [your prior one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/need-messages-in-gmail-trash-to-last-longer)! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only way I can think of is mark all with a label and put them back in your inbox then filter by the label you created select all and archive

EDIT:

Filter by typing `label: trashlabelname` in the serach box, or the label should be on the left hand menu

Comment: how do i filter by the label i've created?

Comment: @Pacerier see edit

Comment: if i filter by **label:temp** it doesn't show me the archive button anymore!

Comment: More Actions button will have the Archive option

Comment: My answer became quite redundant after reading this with proper care.

Comment: @Pacerier adding to "More Actions" you can use [keyboard shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6594) and press `e` for archive.

Answer (score 3):

Simply **move them to Inbox first**, to take 'em out of the Trash. Then proceed as usual.

**If by any chance your inbox isn't empty** (as it should), you should probably **label them before sending to inbox**, so you can easily select them then.

Every organization method in gmail, including folders, is actually just a label hidden or tweaked. Try creating a label "*inbox*", "*trash*" or "*spam*" and you'll see they're already used "*by the system*".

So, archiving is in reality just *removing the inbox label*.

But the system labels each work in its peculiar way and have their own reserved buttons to "add" or "remove" them. In case of trash, that (currently) is "**Move to Inbox**" which will remove the Trash label and add the Inbox.

Comment: dang i really hope they would give a straightforward option to do it. moving those trash to my inbox first will require me to move my current inbox into temp label

Comment: @Pacerier, not if you label all the trash items first with your temp tag, then move them into the inbox, then filter for them and archive.

Comment: @Lance which is precisely what Matt had already suggested and both Pacerier and I overlooked! Sorry, Matt.

Comment: @Lance [quote]not if you label all the trash items first with your temp tag, then move them into the inbox, then filter for them and archive[/quote] which is precisely why they shld give us a straightforward option to do it.